# compare to collection objects

Tags: java

How to compare to ArrayList objects in my project i want to check like this

```
ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
al.add(".net");
al.add("java");
 ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
   list.add(".net");
    list.add("java");
      list.add("iphone")
```

now i want to compare al and list and i want the output is iphone please help me

Comment: I think @duffymo 's edit was good.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`removeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method

```
list.removeAll(a1);
```

Comment: Maybe you should compare to see which list is larger first?

Comment: thanks for the replay in my project i have one enum like public enum profile{username,password} and String s[]={"username","password","phno"} now  i want to compare both and i want the output is phno .for this i am using collections means first i convert enum and string[] into collection  objects then i apply removeall() is it corret way? please help me

Answer (score 1):

`aCollection.removeAll(otherCollection)`
 will remove all elements from aCollection also contained in otherCollection.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i <al.size(); i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
  if((list.get(i).equals(list.get(j)) )
} 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay can i convert the String[] into collections

Comment: yeah,you can convert String Array to List, List a=Arrays.asList(stringarray)